# Numbers of triangles made from sides with length $\le 2n$

Tags: combinatorics

I recently come by this little problem: https://vnexpress.net/dap-an-bai-toan-dem-so-tam-giac-3310485.html. It shows that we can make $50$ triangles with sides equal to $10$ or less. But it is more of listing than math.

I wonder how many triangles can we make with all sides equal or less than $2n$.

Here my approach:

Firstly, there are $2n$ equilateral triangles.

Now I count the number of isosceles triangles:

We call the length of three sides $a, b, c.$

$a=1 \implies $ There are $2n-1$ triangles.

$a=2 \implies $ There are $2n-2$ triangles.

...

$a=2n-1 \implies $ There is one triangle.

So there are $n(2n-1)$ isosceles triangles.

But when it comes to "normal" triangles (whose three sides have different lengths), I don't know how to count at all. Can you give me some advice on how to progress? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the two smaller sides fixed, how many do you count? Then sum for all possible choices for the smaller sides

Comment: Alternatively, let the three sides be $x+y,y+z,x+z$, where $x \ge y \ge z \ge 0$. what do you get?

Comment: It seems to me that your source assumes that all three sides are different. Therefore, 50 isn't the correct answer for the problem you posed.

Comment: @mathlander actually in my source he calculated all triangles that can be made. I just wonder how many can be made from n sides. I looked up and found a post calculating 2n lengths  but with no solutions